# $Z_A := \{B \in \mathbb{K}^{n,n}:AB = BA\}$ A,B matrices. Proof $Z_A$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-subalgebra of $\mathbb{K^{n,n}}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $Z_A := \{B \in \mathbb{K}^{n,n}:AB = BA\}, n \in \mathbb{N^*}, \mathbb{K}$ a field and A, B be the set of muliplicative interchangable matrices. Proof, that  $Z_A$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-subalgebra of $\mathbb{K^{n,n}}$.

The only property Im failing to prove is, that **if you multiply A and B that the solution is in $Z_A$**. In other words that if you multiply two multiplicative interchangable matrices you get another one.

I found out that for commutative matrices there exist common Eigenvalues/Eigenvectors, that might be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given a fixed $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$, then you want to show that the set 
\begin{align} 
Z_A:= \{ B \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n} \mid AB =BA \} \subset \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}
\end{align}
is a subalgebra of $\mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$.
Since $\mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ is an algebra, you only have to show that $Z_A$ is closed under addition, multiplication and scalar multiplication.
Thus if you take $B,C \in Z_A$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$, you must show that $B+C,BC,\lambda B \in Z_A$.
Thus you must show that $a(B+C)=(B+C)A$, $a(BC)=(BC)A$ and $A(\lambda B)=(\lambda B)A$.

We now show that $BC \in Z_A$ by using the facts that $AB=BA$, $AC = CA$ and that the multiplication is associative, thus it does not matter if we multiply $A$ with $BC$ to obtain $A(BC)$ or $AB$ with $C$ to obtain $(AB)C$, as they are the same. Then we get
\begin{align}
A(BC)=(AB)C=(BA)C=B(AC)=B(CA)=(BC)A.
\end{align}
So we see that $A(BC) =(BC)A$, and thus that $BC \in Z_A$.

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind your solution? I just don't get it

Comment: @WhatAMesh, see if this helps.

Comment: Well, thanks to you I finally understood this question, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need eigenvectors for this, just computation. Let $B, C \in Z_A$, we will show $(BC)A = A(BC)$, that is $BC \in Z_A$: 
$$ (BC)A = B(CA) = B(AC)= (BA)C= (AB)C = A(BC). $$

Comment: $16$ seconds faster, have an upvote.

Comment: Is $A \in Z_A$ too? Can you explain your Idea a bit? I don't get what has been done here